# Charset specific chars work in IDE, but not on live

Tags: java, character-encoding

So heres my problem. I'm reading a json from web using `httpurlconnection`. That json contains german special chars (äöü). Inside NetBeans, everything is fine. When I build the jar an run it, "Silberanhänger" changes to "SilberanhÃ¤nger". Heres the code, nothing special inside

```
URL url = new URL("jsonUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"); 
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie","s="+session);
try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     con.getInputStream()))) {
            jsonRepresentation = bf.readLine(); //only 1 line
}
con.disconnect();
System.out.println(jsonRepresentation) // "ä" in IDE, "Ã¤" in Live
```

Comment: have you tried setting the jvm encoding -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 ?

Comment: thank you for this. running the jar with that parameter immediately solved the issue. however, can we get this into the code? it looks like {code}System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF8");{/code} doesnt have any influence.

Comment: You can't do it at runtime, you can find a detailed answer as to why this is the case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: red the whole thing + oracle bugreport. what i yet not understand is why my jvm doesnt use 8tf8 at all, since i yet told my netbeans project to do so in the project properties.

Comment: The netbean project properties are only used by netbeans, they don't have anything todo with the compiled and deployed project. When a JVM starts up it uses the standard system encoding by default, unless you override it by setting enviorment variable.

Comment: i see. so i have to deal with delivering a .bat/.sh bundle together with my .jar :(. thanks for your help mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` is a hack that will have side-effects on all code run on that JVM. A better hack would be to specify the charset in the InputStreamReader's constructor

```
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
```

However this might still fail if the HTTP server on the other end changes its encoding. You would be better off using a HTTP library such as Apache HTTPComponents to parse the HTTP response into a `String`. It will read the encoding from the HTTP header and do the right thing in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Set jvm encoding with -Dfile.encoding=UTF8